# Initial Request Slow on Lamda Due to DB connection

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-documentdb

When my lambda function is activated it connects to my MongoDB Atlas instance, significantly slowing down the response by 1000-2000ms

I can cache the DB connection, but the cache only lasts if requests are made quickly after the last one and would not persist for a request made an hour later.

Do any of the native AWS DB's avoid this problem and allow an instant connection every time? (documentDB, DynamoDB etc)

CODE

```
let response
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'
let cachedDb = null
const uri =
    'mongodb+srv://XXXX'

function connectToDatabase(uri) {
    if (cachedDb && cachedDb.serverConfig.isConnected()) {
        console.log('=> using cached database instance')
        return Promise.resolve(cachedDb)
    }
    const dbName = 'test'
    return MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(
        client => {
            cachedDb = client.db(dbName)
            return cachedDb
        }
    )
}

export async function lambdaHandler() {
    try {
        const client = await connectToDatabase(uri)
        const collection = client.collection('users')

        const profile = await collection.findOne({ user: 'myuser' })

      response = profile
    }

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return err
    }
    return response
}
```

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: @danimal added JS / TS code

Comment: What is average idle time after which connection takes too long again?

Comment: 1500~ ms roughly which makes the app feel slow. I don't have a lot of requests at the moment, hence why I'm using lambda. The problem is the majority of requests will probably be cold starting and not using the cache.

Comment: 1500ms (1 and a half second) between requests is not enough to get cold start. Normally it happens after 5minutes.

Comment: Misread your question, the coldboot response is 1.5 seconds which is too long. Requests could be hours apart. So most will be cold booting.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue with mysql connections, the cached variables disappear when the lambda function cold starts. 
The only solution I have is to keep the cache alive with function warming.
Just set up a periodic cron job to trigger your function every 5-15 minutes, and rest assured, it will always be idle.
You can check also this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-warmer

Comment: Ahh thats a shame I was hoping that by switching to DynamoDB it would fix it

Answer (score 1):

You are facing cold start. It's not related to DB connection.

In order to keep you lambda function warm you can set up CloudWatch event that will trigger Lambda periodically (normally once per 5 minutes should be enough).

Also if you are using `DocumentDB`, you must put `Lambda` into `VPC`. It requires `ENI` (Elastic Network Interface) to be provisioned therefore it adds more time to start. So for example if you can avoid using VPC, then it could give you some performance advantages.

More info:

- [Good article about cold start](https://hackernoon.com/im-afraid-you-re-thinking-about-aws-lambda-cold-starts-all-wrong-7d907f278a4f)
- [AWS Lambda Execution Context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html)